# Filtering on number of times a value appears in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have a file with a column containing IDs.  Usually, an ID appears only once, but occasionally, they're associated with multiple records.  I want to count how many times a given ID appeared, and then split into two separate dfs so I can run different operations on both.  One df should be where IDs only appear once, and one should be where IDs appear multiple times.

I was able to successfully count the number of instances an ID appeared by grouping on ID and joining the counts back onto the original df, like so:

```
newdf = df.join(df.groupBy('ID').count(),on='ID')
```

This works nicely, as I get an output like so:

```
ID      Thing  count
287099  Foo     3
287099  Bar     3
287099  Foobar  3
321244  Barbar  1
333032  Barfoo  2
333032  Foofoo  2
```

But, now I want to split the df so that I have a df where count = 1, and count > 1.  The below and variations thereof didn't work, however:

```
singular = df2.filter(df2.count == 1)
```

I get a 'TypeError: condition should be string or Column' error instead.  When I tried displaying the type of the column, it says the count column is an instance.  How can I get PySpark to treat the count column the way I need it to?

Answer (score 2):

count is a method of dataframe,

```
>>> df2.count
<bound method DataFrame.count of DataFrame[id: bigint, count: bigint]>
```

Where as filter needs a column to operate on, change it as below,

```
singular = df2.filter(df2['count'] == 1)
```