# Pyspark dataframe filter using occurrence based on column

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have pyspark dataframe and I want to filter dataframe with columns A and B. Now I want to get only values of B where occurrence of A is greater than some number N.

Column A is like and id which can have repeated values. Right now I am doing group by and the filtering and using list of values which is not efficient so I am looking for efficient solution.

Example

N = 5

Input [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhOXN.jpg)

Expected Output [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv1hV.jpg)

You can see there that only ID1 and ID3 of column A is selected because of threshold of 5 rest all are excluded.

Comment: can you share your tryings?

Comment: You may want to look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395093/filtering-on-number-of-times-a-value-appears-in-pyspark

Answer (score 1):

Try the follwoing:

```
df = ... # The dataframe
N = 5 # The value to test
df_b = df.filter(df['A'] >= N).select('B')
```

This will first filter the dataframe only containing rows where A is >= N with its corresponding 'B' values. After applying the filter select only column B to obtain the final result.

Comment: I think this not what I am looking for. I think you missed the point of occurrences. please read question carefully. If this was as simple as that I wouldn't have posted question :)

Comment: Then please give an example of input and expected output. Whats the correct understanding of "repeated values"? Is it a nested structure like a list? concatenated values?

Comment: repeated means duplicate values.

Comment: So what you actualy want is the key (A) values with its corresponding B values like ID1: [B1, B6, B7...] ?

Comment: Yes you can find more by looking into input and output